# How can a static property be set to a value only for a specific element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, static

If `Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled` is a static property of the `Stylus` class, shouldn't its value be global? How can a value be set to it just for one element, like a button?

```
<Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="False"/>
```

This is of course a general question that applies to more than just this class and property. I'm just trying to understand how WPF works. I'd appreciate any links that touch on this topic.

Comment: reference of control is passed to SetValue and GetValue. If you dig in you will see that these references are stored in a dicationary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These properties are **Dependency Properties** and **Attached Properties** (a special case of dependency properties). They are *technically* static, but what you don't see are generated calls to `GetValue` and `SetValue` that do take the control instance in question. The `static` piece is really just setting up the property so the framework knows about it.

You can actually see these calls in the normal properties generated by the `propdp` snippet (note that these properties are never called by the framework, they are just for your convenience).